# Can Saitama breathe in space?

Tags: one-punch-man

I'm just wondering whether Saitama could live in space, just like Superman or Goku, without needing oxygen to breathe?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**No, he can not breathe in space.**

In the chapter 47 (35.2), Boros punches Saitama so hard that he is sent flying towards the moon. When he lands there, he does his best to hold his breath:

[image: Saitama]

Comment: The real question is "can he resists space radiation?"

Comment: I don't think short term exposure to outer space is dangerous for radiation first. Rather, insanely low temperature.

Comment: The pressure would kill a person anyway :p

Comment: His resistance to punches kind of implies resistance to pressure changes.

Comment: Space, which is a vacuum, has very low pressure. This drops the boiling point of water to very low temperature. Therefore, the first side effect of outer space will be that your blood start boiling. There are better ways to go!

Comment: Your blood wouldn't start boiling for a while. The fluid in your eyes and mouth on the other hand, will in fact suffer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the anime, Saitama first looks around calmly, realizes he's in space, then covers his nose. While this isn't solid evidence, the fact he just didn't even realize this is probable evidence of one of two things: either Saitama does not require any breath and had passively stopped breathing at all, or he is simply such a broken character that he ignores logic until he realizes it's even there in the first place. Either way the air should have escaped from his body within seconds, so based on a logical standpoint I can only assume that yes, Saitama can breathe in space.

Answer (score 0):

No he can't. He had to hold his breath while in the moon. That means no. However he can travel through space without external help. He got shot to the moon and he got back without a rocket. His durability and endurance is enough for that.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how strong he may be, Saitama wasn't holding his breath until after a few seconds of being on the moon. the minute he left the atmosphere, the air inside him, which is normal oxygen and nitrogen, would be sucked out. Strength has nothing to do with his oxygen deprivation. No breath holding equals no oxygen, so no reaction to oxygen loss equals no oxygen dependency. Saitama can't die from space.